# Babel not transpiling arrow functions (Webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

When running webpack, and babel, the resulting bundle.js still contains arrow functions. This gives me a Syntax Error when running in Internet Explorer 10. I would like babel to replace the arrow functions with normal functions that IE can run.

My **package.json** has the following devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
  "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
  "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
  "webpack": "^3.11.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2"
}
```

My **webpack.config.js** looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    enforceExtension: false,
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 5000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

My **.babelrc** looks like this:

```
{ 
  "presets": 
  [
    ["env", { "targets": {"browsers": ["last 2 versions"]}, "debug": true }], 
    "react", 
    "stage-3"
  ]
}
```

To transpile, I run the command:

> npm run build --production

And I get the following output in the console:

```
Using targets:
{
  "chrome": "62",
  "android": "4.4.3",
  "edge": "15",
  "firefox": "56",
  "ie": "10",
  "ios": "10.3",
  "safari": "10.1"
}

Modules transform: commonjs

Using plugins:
  check-es2015-constants {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-arrow-functions {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-block-scoping {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-classes {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-computed-properties {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-destructuring {"android":"4.4.3","edge":"15","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-duplicate-keys {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-for-of {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-function-name {"android":"4.4.3","edge":"15","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-literals {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-object-super {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-parameters {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-shorthand-properties {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-spread {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-sticky-regex {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-template-literals {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-typeof-symbol {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-es2015-unicode-regex {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-regenerator {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-exponentiation-operator {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  transform-async-to-generator {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
  syntax-trailing-function-commas {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"10"}
```

The transform-es2015-arrow-functions is listed as included, but when I open the generated bundle.js I can, for instance, see the following:

```
...

function encoderForArrayFormat(options) {
    switch (options.arrayFormat) {
        case 'index':
            return (key, value, index) => {
                return value === null ? [
                    encode(key, options),
...
```

The above makes use of an arrow function, and produces a syntax error in Internet Explorer. Other ES6 stuff like '...' gets transpiled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I thought babellrc should be object instead of Array? [Document](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/)

Comment: Well, It *is an object containing presents that are in an array.

Comment: Ah I see, `spread function` can be transpiled

Comment: Yes, spread syntax seems to work, and I don't get any errors when I generate bundle.js.

Comment: use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                        },
                    }
                ]

Try using es2015 instead of stage

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried, but it doesn't make any difference. Also, es2005 is now depricated. I need stage-3 to get the spread syntax to compile.

Comment: @Henrik: Maybe you can post your question [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) to find the anwser

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think an issue is related to [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) because it's written in ES6 and not transpiled to ES5. Try to downgrade version from 6 to 5.

```
yarn add query-string@5.1.1
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable. I'll check.

Comment: @Henrik no problem :)

Comment: I ran into the same problem and query-string@5.1.1 fixed it for me, too. Why isn't it transpiled to ES5 by webpack/babel?

Comment: @Vetterjack It's a decision of query-string creators. They have a note under [Install](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#install) section.

Comment: @SerhiiLevchenko Thanks for that hint! So webpack with babel setup does not transpile ES6+ packages/libraries to ES5/3?

Comment: @Vetterjack it depends on your webpack configuration.

Comment: Thanks! Stupid decision by the authors, shouldn't complain though, it's open source :)

Comment: Wasted 2 days to find this root cause. :(. It worked after changing version

Comment: How can one configure the build to have modules also transpiled?

Comment: You save the day. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SerhiiLevchenko You can just add it to the `babel-loader` rule as `include`, no need to downgrade.

Comment: @SerhiiLevchenko Do you have a patreon? I owe you coffee.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the webpack bundle file
2. Edit the webpack config file
3. Disable arrowFunction
4. Run webpack

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    environment: {
      arrowFunction: false
    }
  }
}
```

More info here: [Top level function is still arrow on Webpack 5](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#top-level-function-iife-is-still-arrow-on-webpack-5)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the arrow functions in the assembly, which broke the Internet Explorer. Such a solution has come - we just forcibly run the ES packages with a babel with the included plugin for replacing arrow functions.

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: {
            {
                test: /\.(js|cjs|mjs|tsx|jsx)$/,
                include: [
                    /node_modules[/\\]query-string/,
                    /node_modules[/\\]abort-controller/,
                    /node_modules[/\\]phoenix/,
                ],
                loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
                options: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                    plugins: [
                        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
                        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
                        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
                        "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions", // <--- at least this one
                    ],
                },
            },
            // ... rest of your rules
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

it seems to be related to 'transform-es2015-function-name' plugin.
see https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4782#issuecomment-271367012 for details.
So excluding the plugin should do the job.

Answer (score -2):

Please try to use the **preset-env** dependency.
It worked for me just fine

```
{
   test: /\.js$/,
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   loader: 'babel-loader',
   options: {
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
   }
},
```