# How to transpile every dependency in a React app using Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, transpiler

I am developing an app using react and it needs to run on IE. I'm using an external library called `query-string`. It contains arrow functions and IE doesn't know those and for some reason the code in this library is not transpiled or translated to older JS.

I had similar issue within this project with the library `popmotion` which was using a find method, but I fixed that by installing Babel polyfill and including it in the main file App.jsx. I did not eject the react app as I'm quite new to this and don't know exactly how react works under the hood.

This is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "ruzovky",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "deepcopy": "^1.0.0",
        "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.3",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
        "popmotion": "^8.3.4",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
        "query-string": "^6.1.0",
        "react": "^16.4.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
        "watch-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch",
        "start-js": "react-scripts start",
        "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
        "build-js": "react-scripts build",
        "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
}
```

To help you understand my issue: Everything else does get transpiled, as react takes care of everything (I can create react components using javascript, which no browser supports yet), except this single library. In my node_modules folder there is babel-loader and webpack too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use build tool, the simplest & most widespread one is [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Here is the tutorial on how to transpile ES6 to older versions via [webpack](http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial/setup-webpack/)

Comment: isn't react using that by default ? i created the app using create-react-app and I have a webpack folder in node_modules

Comment: also the webpage which is displayed has a single link to a single bundle.js. Is that webpack in the works ? Thanks for the fast reply

Comment: How are you starting your app?

Comment: npm start which is actually this "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js" as I am using sass, this setup is taken from official react github page

Comment: I edtied my question which now has my package.json

Comment: There is an answer to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954618/babel-not-transpiling-arrow-functions-webpack, the solution is to use older version of query-string

Comment: create-react-app v2 transpiles dependencies by default