# React app is not working in IE 11 browser

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, create-react-app, polyfills

I have seen a lot of similar questions here and I have tried all the ways but I have no idea why still not showing anything.

1. npm install react-app-polyfill
2. I added "ie 11" to production and development array in package.json
3. Add this two-line `import "react-app-polyfill/ie11";`
   `import "react-app-polyfill/stable";` to top of `index.js`
4. delete .cache folder inside node_modules
5. Restart App

But still not showing anything in ie 11.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "firealarm",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "antd": "^3.26.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.2.11",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      "ie 11",
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I even remove the node_modules folder and install `npm` again but still not working.

Update

I got two error message in IE 11.

```
SCRIPT5022: SyntaxError
File: 0.chunk.js, Line: 176128, Column: 38
```

And

```
SCRIPT5022: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
File: 0.chunk.js, Line: 205780, Column: 64
```

.

Comment: In explorer console are there any errors?  Did you create the app with create-react-app?

Comment: @SuleymanSah, Please check for error, yes I created with create-react-app.

Comment: Loran did you add any code or do you just try with an empty app?

Comment: @SuleymanSah, App is already finished. and All along the way, I tested with chrome and its working. but when I test with IE, I got this issue.

Comment: After you delete .cache folder in node_modules,  can you also clear internet explorer's cache and retry?

Comment: @SuleymanSah, I tried but still not working.anything I can try?

Comment: I see you already tried lots of suggesstions. Can you create a new app and try your solution to see if it works or not?

Comment: @SuleymanSah, I create a new blank app by using create-react-app and I install polyfill but still not working at Internet explorer.

Comment: did you apply all of the steps in new project?

Comment: @SuleymanSah, Yes, I also tried with babel/polyfill but still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204933/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-loran).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486715/react-development-and-build-version-not-working-in-ie-11-and-edge-webpack-babe

Comment: Have you tried Compatibility Mode in IE11, does it helps?

Answer (score 6):

What is your `react-scripts` version? It seems an issue with `react-scripts` version 3.3.0. You could find the issue report in GitHub: [issue 1](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197), [issue 2](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195).

It can still work with `react-scripts@3.2.0`. You could try to revert back to 3.2.0 as a workaround. Please also remember to delete `.cache` folder in `node_modules` and delete IE browser cache then try again.

Comment: react-scripts@3.2.0 did it for me. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Go to > /node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js:60;
add **slashes: true**

Below is the code sample

```
{
// Connect to WebpackDevServer via a socket.
var connection = new WebSocket(
  url.format({
    protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws',
    hostname: window.location.hostname,
    port: window.location.port,
    //Hardcoded in WebpackDevServer
    pathname: '/sockjs-node',
    slashes: true,
  })
);
}
```

Comment: this is it right here.
Now use a cra webpack addon to edit tis webpack base config and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on edge browser, `npm start` gives the same error you mentioned, but you say that you just want to run your app on ie11. I did `npm run build` and served it via `serve` package(after `npm i -g serve`), it works fine.
Unless until if you would like to development in ie, if you are able to run your app on ie locally that will help I guess.

Answer (score 0):

add @babel/preset-env in .bablerc or babel-config {loose:true} it worked for me

```
"@babel/preset-env": { "targets":">0.2%, not dead","loose":true}
```